# Swiftmailer single quote / apostrophe in setTo() breaks message sending

Tags: php, sendmail, swiftmailer

I am using SwiftMailer to send emails and I am using the setTo() method to set the email address and the display name

e.g. `->setTo("user@email.com", "User Name")`

When the user name contains a single quote / apostrophe the message send fails. I've tried using addslashes() on the username to escape the string but it still fails.

How do I handle setting the display name when it contains a single quote / apostrophe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the single quote wasn't the actual problem. The problem was actually with the server configuration not allowing email to be sent to any domain outside its own.